# JGit/EGit crashing on branch deletion/creation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, github, egit, jgit

I am trying to delete a branch from Git repositories view in eclipse Juno, running on Mac OS X lion, 64 bit.

I get the following error log while I try to do so, and the changes are not reflected in the remote repository.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RevisionSyntaxException:refs/remotes/origin/IMAdNetwork_3.5.4@8578
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.resolve(Repository.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.resolve(Repository.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositoriesViewLabelProvider.decorateImage(RepositoriesViewLabelProvider.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.repository.RepositoriesViewLabelProvider.getImage(RepositoriesViewLabelProvider.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateCommonLabelProvider.getImage(SafeDelegateCommonLabelProvider.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1500)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(TreeViewer.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$4.treeExpanded(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.sendExpand(TreeItem.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.expandItem_expandChildren(Tree.java:1248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5760)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDownSuper(Widget.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDownSuper(Tree.java:2052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.mouseDown(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.mouseDown(Control.java:2538)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.mouseDown(Tree.java:2007)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5493)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2284)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5557)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5002)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3616)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

What could be causing this? Are there any other git team providers for eclipse?

Comment: Does the remote origin really have a branch named "IMAdNetwork_3.5.4@8578"?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that the problem happens when calculating the decorations of one of the trees in Eclipse. So a workaround might be to disable the git decorations in *Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations*. If that does not work, you might try the more fain grained label preferences under *Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Label Decorations*.

Besides that, egit 2.1 was released just 6 days ago, so chances are high you are not on the latest version of egit and an update might also solve your problem.

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Installed 1.3 and that solved the issue.

Comment: Consider filing a bug report against 2.1 then.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed v1.3 and that worked.