# git-svn creates duplicate tags with "@" (at sign) in name

Tags: git, svn, tags, git-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git-svn clone | spurious branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356901/git-svn-clone-spurious-branches)

When cloning an SVN repository, `git svn` creates funny tags: For many (but not all) tags in the SVN repository, two git tags are created, one with an at sign. For example:

- release-1.0
- release-1.0@1523
- release-1.1
- release-1.1@1783

etc.

The number is different for each tag, but apparently it is the SVN revision  when the tag was created, minus 1.

Funnily enough, the tags created point to different commit objects, but the two commit objects have the same tree (i.e. the tags contain the same files).

This is rather annoying, because a) it messes up the list of tags, and b) it crashes EGit in Eclipse (looks like [JGit/EGit crashing on branch deletion/creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727333/jgit-egit-crashing-on-branch-deletion-creation) is the same problem).

I have not found any info on this in the git-svn docs, or by googling. Any idea where these tags come from, and how to avoid them?

---

Some more info: There are funny log entries for each funny tag in the git-svn output (somewhat sanitized):

```
Found possible branch point: [...]
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/release-1.0@1523
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): 
Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 101, path [...]
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356901/git-svn-clone-spurious-branches

Comment: @eckes: Yes, it's  a duplicate. I voted to close my question.